# Parallel testing on android

Tags: android, selenium, appium, selenium-grid

I successfully configured my selenium grid with appium. I successfully created to the driver for two different android devices. Let's say d1 and d2. now I want to maintain sink in between them means my driver does some operation using d1 and then after completing that another operation on driver d2. When I am doing operation on d2 another driver d1 should be ideal
  But when I am doing the operation on 2nd driver then on first device the app is in the background after switching to the first device
it gives me an error that session is not valid.please help me out here, what should I do? should I implement multi-threading ? or is there any way to put the first driver on ideal state while second is doing that operation?

```
import io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.ObjectUtils.Null;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterClass;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class selenium_grid_example
{

    AppiumDriver d1,d2;
    String id = null;
    DesiredCapabilities capabilities2= new DesiredCapabilities();

    @Test(priority=1)
    public void two_driver() throws InterruptedException{
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities1= new DesiredCapabilities();
        capabilities1.setCapability("deviceName","xxxx");
        capabilities1.setCapability("platformVersion", "5.1");
        capabilities1.setCapability("appPackage", "xxxx);          
        capabilities1.setCapability("appActivity", "xxxx");
        capabilities1.setCapability("udid", "xxxx");
        capabilities1.setCapability("commandTimeout", 10000);
        try {
            d1 = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4728/wd/hub"),        capabilities1);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            System.out.println("Not able to start application");
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
    d1.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10000, TimeUnit.SECONDS);




capabilities2.setCapability("deviceName","xxxx");
    capabilities2.setCapability("platformVersion", "xxx");
    //capabilities.setCapability("app",app.getAbsolutepath());
    capabilities2.setCapability("appPackage", "xxxx");          
    capabilities2.setCapability("appActivity", "xxxx");
    capabilities2.setCapability("udid", "xxxx");
    capabilities2.setCapability("commandTimeout", 1000);
    d2.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10000, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

}


@Test(priority=2)
public void login_to_application() throws MalformedURLException, InterruptedException{
    here i am doing some operation on driver d1         
    d1.manage().wait(20000);

}

@Test(priority=3)
   public void join_meeting(){
        try {
            d2= new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4730/wd/hub"),     capabilities2);
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            here i am doing another operation on driver d2
            when i am doing some operation here previously opened app get in background on device one 

        }   
    }
    @AfterClass
    public void quit_driver(){
        try {
            Thread.sleep(40000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Quiting driver");
        d1.quit();
    d2.quit();
    System.out.println("Driver quited successfully");
    }

}}
```

**here i got this error**

```
    org.openqa.selenium.remote.SessionNotFoundException: 
Command duration or timeout: 9 milliseconds
Build info: version: 2.45.0, revision: 32a636c, time: 2015-03-05 22:01:35
System info: host: gs-1783, ip: 10.22.99.156, os.name: Windows 8, os.arch: amd64, os.version: 6.2, java.version: 1.8.0_45
Driver info: io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver
Capabilities [{appPackage=com.fuze.fuzemeeting, networkConnectionEnabled=true, warnings={}, commandTimeout=10000, databaseEnabled=false, deviceName=Nexus, platform=LINUX, appActivity=com.fuze.fuzemeeting.ui.FuzeMainActivity, desired={appPackage=com.fuze.fuzemeeting, appActivity=com.fuze.fuzemeeting.ui.FuzeMainActivity, platformVersion=5.1, commandTimeout=10000, udid=0aee8e8b02e4223e, platformName=Android, deviceName=Nexus}, platformVersion=5.1, webStorageEnabled=false, locationContextEnabled=false, browserName=Android, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, udid=0aee8e8b02e4223e, platformName=Android}]
Session ID: 46ce15cd-1e05-4d6a-a460-360dd64c0782
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:204)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:162)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:599)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.execute(AppiumDriver.java:180)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.execute(AppiumDriver.java:185)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.quit(RemoteWebDriver.java:468)
    at selenium_grid_example.quit_driver(selenium_grid_example.java:136)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:84)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:564)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:213)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:138)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeAfterClassMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:225)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:114)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1224)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1149)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1057)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:111)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:204)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:175)
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is issue is caused from both Sessions attempting to use the same chrome-driver port.

When starting a Selenium Grid node use:

`appium --nodeconfig /Path/to/Config.json -p XXXX -bp YYYY --chromedriver-port ZZZZ;`

Make sure to specify three separate ports for each node.

Hope this helps,

Liam